# Connection to sql database from visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect to a database, I also have a bool function to check if the connection worked. I searched all over the internet but can't really find how to do it properly.

```
public class DBConnection : DBLabsDLL.DBConnectionBase
{

///*
// * The constructor
// */
public DBConnection()
{
    string connectionString = null;
    SqlConnection connection;
    connectionString = "Data Source=SQL Server;Initial Catalog=www3.idt.mdh.se;User ID=ezi15001;Password=********";

    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}


public override bool login(string username, string password)
{

    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        {
            connection.Open();
        return true;

    }
    catch (SqlException)

    {
     return false; 
    }

}
```

Comment: What specifically are you having a problem with? (apart from your code not compiling due to the missing `}`)? I also notice that you are assigning your `connection` variable twice, which seems a bit odd. And you're not using `username` or `password` variables. There's quite a few problems with this code, but without knowing what you would like to achieve, it's hard to rewrite it...

Comment: My problem is in the bool function, dont really know how to use the username and password to test the connection

Comment: @alifarlig You'll need to construct a new connection string using your `username` and `password`. Take a look at the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class, which makes this much easier. You should also make your class implement `IDisposable` so that the connection can be disposed of later. Finally, remove all the work being done by the constructor. The constructor should just take the server name, initial catalog, and other essential connection details and store them to be used by your `login` method.

Comment: Google for "connection string", there are many thousands of examples.

Comment: As RB said, you're missing a closing }. In addition, the scope of the connection variable in the login method is very limited. . It will cease to exist when you exit the login method. Were you hoping to execute queries against this connection?